# C# - Silverlight - Custom control or UserControl?

Tags: c#, silverlight, user-controls

I need a button that is visually completely customizable, but has custom logic to publish events and manage it's visual state based on events it has registered for.

When I say visually customizable, I mean I should be able to both create the button in xaml and set it's style by binding to the supplied style. Or I can create an instance of the button  and set the style by passing a parameter to an alternate constructor. Or by calling a method on the button class to set the style.

I do not plan on substituting the controls template, it should be a button. Can anyone point me to some code samples of this?

Comment: "Visually completely customizable" and "I do not plan on substituting the controls template", which is it?  It can't be both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to allow the control to be templated (I would generally recommend you do, but you don't have to) than a UserControl would work well.  A simple user control that exposes a `ButtonStyle` property that is applied to a specific control should solve your needs.

Comment: Making this into a custom control would take much more work wouldn't it?

Comment: How do I provide its template through the constructor?

Comment: I wanted to state of the control (active/inactive) to be handled internally, but that does not apply to all types of controls. Say I user wants to load a ViewB clicking a button for that, then that button would be rendered as active. If they user needed to select ViewB from a dropdown then there is no active state.

Comment: I guess i'm looking for something akin to the hyperlinkbutton.

Comment: Are you wanting to template the control yourself or let the users of the your control retemplate what the button should look like?

Comment: The control is a button, but the user can change the style for the base state and other states.

Answer (score 0):

Totally depends on your application. I create ContentControl derivatives much more often than UserControl, if only for the glint of hope that they may be useful in the future.

I have written before:

> UserControls are content controls that are optimized for simple design-time use, typically for sharing within an application, but not with other applications.
>
> Component libraries should never contain UserControl implementations.